# Right-Aligned Image with Pauses in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, pause

See the end for code.

Let's say I have a frame in Beamer, and I want it to open with an image visible in a right column. I then want the text to appear with button presses (thus, pauses). How do I do this?

Below is example code of a left-aligned image that works perfect, but I need to move it to the right side:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Marburg}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
  \setbeamercolor{author in sidebar}{fg = purple}
  \setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg = white}
  \setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{fg = purple}
  \setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg = pink}
  \useinnertheme{default}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ulem}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example}
  \begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{EXAMPLE A}\pause
      \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1\pause
      \item Item 2\pause
      \item Item 3
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your codesnippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Mensch Yeah sure I'll add that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `column` environment within the `columns` environment. You can use the `\column` command to create a new column. Subsequent columns will appear to the right of existing columns, so put the code for your list, then create a new column containing your figure. Also, you don't need a `figure` environment unless you specifically want the caption.

The `\pause` command is not limited to the `columns` environment, thus pauses everything thereafter. You have much better control using overlay specifications (see section 9 in the `beamer` documentation). Adding `[<+->]` after `\begin{itemize}` will increment the list (`+`) and keep items visible thereafter (`-`). This does not affect the other column containing the figure.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Marburg}
  \usecolortheme{beaver}
  \useinnertheme{default}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width = \linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{EXAMPLE A}
    \end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that the OP wants the image on the right visible on all the slides... maybe you need to use explicit `<>` overlays.

Comment: Thanks @Rmano! Edited.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to show the picture and hide "item 1" until after the first button press?

Comment: Found it! Thanks for mentioning the documentation, I checked section 9 and found I could do [<+(1)->]

Comment: @TheAkashain you can also go manual and use `<1>`, `<2->` ,`<3->` etc in specific items. That way you can also use a specific `<>` specifier for you `\column` and make that appears when you like (for example, `<2-4>` to make it visible in steps 2,3,4... *independently* from its position in the input file. Really, `\pause` is ok just for simple, linear things...